# How do I save all query commands and output into .sql file?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a mysql newbie. So I did several queries and got the results. How do I save everything (including query commands) into a .sql file? Copy and paste? What if the result is long? Or mysqldump (didn't work for me---couldn't find the query commands) Any input is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You mean a `*.txt` or `*.log` file, right? Because a `*.sql` file (or "SQL script") is normally intended to be executed by the database software, so it normally includes *only* statements (no results).

Comment: It depends on what tool (if any) you use to write and execute your queries (plain simply mysql, phpMyAdmin, SequelPro etc).

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -user -pass -e "SELECT cols FROM table WHERE cols NOT null" > /yourfolder/output.sql
```

This saves the output to `/tmp/output.sql`. `.sql` is not recommended to save plain texts though.

Try using `.txt` or `.log` etc. to save screen output.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [`tee` command built into the MySQL client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html).

```
mysql> tee myoutputfile.txt
Logging to file 'myoutputfile.txt'
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2013-03-11 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> notee
Outfile disabled.
mysql> quit
Bye

$ cat myoutputfile.txt 
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2013-03-11 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> notee

$
```